# how to filter based on roledefinitionbinding hidden property?

Tags: rest

```
/servername/_api/web/lists(guid'myistid')/items(6)/roleassignments?$expand=member,RoleDefinitionBindings/hidden&$select=member,RoleDefinitionBindings/hidden&$filter=RoleDefinitionBindings/hidden%20eq%20fals
```

I need to apply `$filter` on the hidden property of `roledefinitionBindings` which is a collection. Any thoughts?

I get the error:

> Invalid clientQuery exception. value=Field or property "hidden" does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported to apply `$filter` query option to [SP.RoleAssignment.roleDefinitionBindings property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246295.aspx)  since its return value is [SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246295.aspx), it is a similar restriction as for *multi-value lookup fields and users*.

According to [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx):

> **Queries for multi-value lookup fields and users** Because multi-value
>   lookup fields are returned as a string of multiple values, there is no
>   way to query for them (for example, the equivalent of an Includes
>   element or NotIncludes element is not supported).

As a workaround, you could consider to apply filtering to the returned results:

```
var endpointUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetById(guid'65cdf954-5169-47b6-9014-0151d2083821')/items(1)/roleassignments?$expand=Member,RoleDefinitionBindings&$select=Member,RoleDefinitionBindings/Hidden";

$.getJSON(endpointUrl, function(data) {
   var roleAssignments  = data.value;
   var result = roleAssignments.filter(function(roleAssignment){
       var roleDefinitionBindings = roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings;
       if(roleDefinitionBindings.length > 0 && !roleDefinitionBindings[0].Hidden) 
         return roleAssignment;
   });

   //print filtered results 
   result.forEach(function(roleAssignment){
       console.log(roleAssignment.Member.Title); 
   });


});
```